# Error when I change variable name in kivy

Tags: python, variables, kivy

I am trying to learn the kivy framework for Python, and for some reason I get an error when I write a variable in a specific way. I must be missing something, but I am not sure what.

**This works fine:
**

```
class WidgetsExample(GridLayout):
    counter = 0
    counter_enabled = BooleanProperty(False)
    slider_enabled = BooleanProperty(False)
    my_text = StringProperty("0")
    slider_value_display = StringProperty("50%")

    def button1_click(self):
        if self.counter_enabled == True:
            self.counter += 1
            self.my_text = str(self.counter)

    def button2_click(self):
        if self.counter_enabled == True:
            self.counter -= 1
            self.my_text = str(self.counter)

    def on_toggle_state(self, widget):
        if widget.state == "normal":
            widget.text = "OFF"
            self.counter_enabled = False
        else:
            widget.text = "ON"
            self.counter_enabled = True

    def on_slider_value(self, widget):
        self.slider_value_display = str(int(widget.value)) + "%"

    def on_active_switch(self, widget):
        print("Switch value: " + str(widget.active))
```

**This crashes when I move the slider:
**

```
class WidgetsExample(GridLayout):
    counter = 0
    counter_enabled = BooleanProperty(False)
    slider_enabled = BooleanProperty(False)
    my_text = StringProperty("0")
    slider_value = StringProperty("50%")

    def button1_click(self):
        if self.counter_enabled == True:
            self.counter += 1
            self.my_text = str(self.counter)

    def button2_click(self):
        if self.counter_enabled == True:
            self.counter -= 1
            self.my_text = str(self.counter)

    def on_toggle_state(self, widget):
        if widget.state == "normal":
            widget.text = "OFF"
            self.counter_enabled = False
        else:
            widget.text = "ON"
            self.counter_enabled = True

    def on_slider_value(self, widget):
        self.slider_value = str(int(widget.value)) + "%"

    def on_active_switch(self, widget):
        print("Switch value: " + str(widget.active))
```

I updated the .kv file to the pertinent variable each time (text: root.slider_value or text: root.slider_value_display)Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: my advice, leave the variable name alone once you find it working.  the code above is not a runnable example so it is hard to know what is happening.  Possibly your problematic variable name is coincidentally the same as something built in.  but rather than worry about it, you could just change the name to something that works and move on

Comment: Please post a [mcve].